# Curry-Howard isomorphism definitions in Coq using fun

Tags: set, definition, coq, isomorphism, curry-howard

I'm having some issues with defining in Coq, more specifically when defining using the CHI. I have managed to gain the understanding of basic principals but when I try to define this"

```
((A -> (A -> C)) * ((A -> C) -> A)) -> C :=
```

I get nowhere due to the fact it keeps telling me:
`"Error: The type of this term is a product while it is expected to be "C"`.
I have already tried the usual tactics I have used earlier in my script and I'm convinced this has to be solved using the same methods (fun) however everything I seem to be trying ends in that error message. Any tips?

Comment: It is hard to say what the problem could be; could you put the rest of your script in here, or a simplified version thereof?

Comment: More infos would be great. It might be a problem of notation scope where ``*`` is interpreted as the multiplication on natural numbers.

Comment: Are you looking for the selectors `fst` and `snd` defined on a product type?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are defining a function that takes as input:

- a function of type `A -> (A -> C)`: given an object of type `A`, it gives back a function of type `A -> C`.
- a function of type `(A -> C) -> A`: given a function of type `A -> C`, it gives back an object of type `A`.

You are trying to build an object of type `C` which I don't see how you will managed to do it. However you can build an object of type `A` by combining the two functions you have as input.

Hope it helps,

V.